# Deno: Denon installation with fish in mac

Tags: fish, deno

Using fish for the installation of denon don't recognize it

steps:

1. Open fish terminal
2. deno install -qAf --unstable https://deno.land/x/denon/denon.ts
3. export PATH="/Users/user/.deno/bin:$PATH"
4. denon --init

output:

```bash
 fish: Unknown command: denon
```

Deno version:

- deno 1.28.3 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
- v8 10.9.194.5
- typescript 4.8.3
- Denon 2.5.0

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
export PATH="/Users/user/.deno/bin:$PATH"                                           ✔  ⬢ 16.17.0 
source ~/.profile
```

you could get the next error:

```
~/.cargo/env (line 4): 'case' builtin not inside of switch block
case ":${PATH}:" in
^
from sourcing file ~/.cargo/env
        called on line 1 of file ~/.profile
from sourcing file ~/.profile
.: Error while reading file '/Users/user/.cargo/env'
```

go to .config/fish/
and `nano config.fish`

and paste the next exports so, it looks like this:

```
if status is-interactive
    # Commands to run in interactive sessions can go here
    export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
    export PATH="/Users/user/.deno/bin:$PATH"
end
```